# New release stuck at Ready to send for review after play store removed the app

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

App was removed due to some Policy Issues but I did changes and can't send it to review:

[image]

I press the button and then again confirm it in the following popup:

[image]

But nothing changes on that page and I can press that button infinitely

Though the following Toast is being shown each time:

[image]

And on the main page it still shows:

[image]

Tried already in a different browser/incognito mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that based on the following message

> You've made some changes that aren't shown in Publishing overview.
> Once they're approved and published, your app will become available
> again on Google Play.

I just have to wait until they approve those "some changes" which are not related to the current review status, so it's a different thing without its own status on the main page

But still it's a weird interface when I can press that button and it will show that toast that it was sent to review... So it's still the issue from their side, not really user-friendly

**Update**

Yes, just needed to wait, now they reviewed it

Comment: Having the same issue. How long did it take Google to review it in your case?